# Mobile close link gets mangled after voting

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, mobile-web

The close link on the mobile site gets mangled if you vote to close something that has existing close votes:

[image: mangled mobile close link]

This is a result of the response handler in `StackExchange.vote_closingAndFlagging` which does

```
b.text(b.text().replace(/\w?\(\d\)/, "") + " " + d.Message)
```

Since the mobile version of the site doesn't generate a space between the "close" and "(#)" portions, the `\w?` matches the "e" in addition to the count and cuts it off.

The mobile version of the site should likely have a space before the vote count, and the intended regular expression was probably `/\s?\(\d\)/` (although removing the extra space isn't strictly necessary).

Comment: I would have probably stopped at the image.  Nice job digging in and finding the cause of the bug.

Comment: I figure they have bigger (and potentially literal) fish to fry on account of the flooding, so I opted to provide as much information as possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just gonna take your word on this one, the space will be there in the next build.