# Bug in close vote display?

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close

Well, I believe this to be a tad minor.. but still a bug nonetheless.

I recall that sometime today, a new display method for close votes was enabled..  next to the close button, instead of `close 1`, it now displayed `close (1/5)`, or similar.. The problem comes in voting to close on a question that already has such.  It instead comes out to be `close (1/5) (2/5)`; example below:

[image]

I suppose I'm wondering if this is indeed a bug, or the intended behavior.. if not, well, here's the report.

Comment: Yep, reproduced. I'd say it's a bug.

Comment: Agreed - just came on here to post that.

Comment: Best guess is that it inserted the 2/5 after recieving an update without clearing the original

Comment: Obligatory eeeeeeeek! :D

Comment: I find your lack of freehand circles disturbing.

Comment: @J.Steen [better](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kvtKZ.png)? ;-)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd You oscillate the cockles of my heart.

Comment: @Marc Is this fixed? I still can reproduce it (or by fixed - does it mean next build)

Comment: @JonClements it will be fixed in the next deploy. If you look in the bottom-right of the page, it says "rev 2013.3.14.856". When it says something else the answer will be "yes"

Comment: @MarcGravell awesome - I'll get ya a pint next time I'm around your area of the woods mate ;)

Comment: @MarcGravell - The issue is not resolved yet. I just voted to close a question and it show me once again. :(

Comment: @hims056 "When it says *something else*". It doesn't say something else yet, so the new revision hasn't been deployed yet.

Comment: @J.Steen - Oh yeh. I extremely need a cup of coffee.

Comment: @hims056 Coffee is very good. I'll have a cup myself, I think. =D

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ah yeah, this [sounds a bit familiar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153248/mobile-close-link-gets-mangled-after-voting). Given that I don't think parentheses ever appear in these links except for in this particular case, that regular expression can probably be genericized to just

```
a.text().replace(/\s?\([^)]+\)$/, "")
```

anyway. Barring that,

```
a.text().replace(/\s?\(\d\/\d\)$/, "")
```

should work too.

There's also extra whitespace on either side of the text, which makes the links display slightly inconsistently from the other options.

Comment: [fixed](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/1732/2007) - I went with `/\w?\(\d(\/\d)?\)/` to go with the two formats we *might expect*

Comment: That's fair. I *still* maintain that `\w?` should be `\s?` though, since it seems to want to remove the space it re-adds during the subsequent string concatenation.

Comment: After years of seeing those, regular expressions still look like [Orz Nemesis battleship](http://wiki.uqm.stack.nl/File:Nemesis_icon.png) to me. :-P

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Trade-off of power in the expression vs. readability. I think APL is the same.

Comment: Just happened to me a minute ago. Not fixed.

Comment: @j08691 not just me then ;)

Comment: @j08691 The fix probably hasn't been deployed yet. I also just saw the problem.

Comment: @andyb - the status is marked as completed though.

Comment: Completed does not mean deployed. I guess it all depends on what the definition of "complete" is. The defect is fixed in `2013.3.14.856`. Current SO version is `2013.3.14.553` so it not deployed to SO yet. It is deployed to meta though (see right column of the footer). If you are still seeing it on meta still then I might agree with you :-)

Comment: I don't like this feature anyway; it makes the spacing all inconsistent.