# Close vote sometimes displays in duplicate

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close

After voting to close as the 2nd vote this appeared:

```
share|edit| close (1/5) (2/5)|flag
```

Which appears to be a UI bug with the new x/y feature.

Comment: [Lemme see if I can reproduce](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171817/bug-in-close-vote-display).

Comment: see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171817/bug-in-close-vote-display

Comment: According to Marc Gravell on that question it was fixed 5 hours ago. djechlin, when did you see the issue?

Comment: @Mike I saw it within a couple minutes of when I posted.  I'll put it this way - I copied and pasted, and posted this question before clearing my clipboard.

Comment: the fix hasn't deployed yet, per Marc's comment: "it will be fixed in the next deploy. If you look in the bottom-right of the page, it says "rev 2013.3.14.856". When it says something else the answer will be "yes"