# Close vote computation bug?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, vote-to-close

I notice the following issue with the close vote display. (Or I misunderstood something with close votes computation)

Here is the question [global in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117410/global-in-matlab) displaying `close (4/5)`

Here is the review link : https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/1768221

The review indicates 3 "Close votes" vs 2 "Leave open".

According my understanding: it must be `close(1/5)` instead of `close(4/5)`

Is it a bug ?

Note: this is not the same as [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171817/bug-in-close-vote-display) bug

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You misunderstood.

The 'leave open' votes will kick the post out of the revew queue if enough have been accumulated, they are not used in the same manner as downvotes as a post.

The [review in question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/1768221) now has gained 3 'Leave open' votes and it has been removed from the review queue. If anyone wants to close it now they'll have to visit the question directly and add their vote to close.

The post has 1 vote close given outside of the review queue; the review only lists votes given via the review queue itself. That 1 vote was probably the initial vote that put the post in the queue in the first place.